# How to change values of a column in a Pyspark dataframe from a map of two columns of the same df

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a dataframe say df, with multiple columns. I now create a dataframe from df, say map, passing only columns A and B and keeping only the unique rows. Now I want to modify df in such a way such that, if for a row in df, I find df['B'] in the map, then df['A'] should be key value from the map otherwise df['A' remains the same.

Any useful suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show code example, what you've tried?

Comment: It would be useful if you spend some more time on the question to elaborate more. it will be helpful for you to get quality answers.